# Is it bad to have 2 modules in a package?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a package `MyTest`,

```
MyTest/src/MyTest.jl
MyTest/src/A.jl

A.jl:
    module A ... end

MyTest.jl
    module MyTest
    using A
    ...
    end
```

When I loaded the package from `Pkg.clone("..")` and `using MyTest`, it complained that it could not find `A`. What's the standard way to deal with multiple modules in a package? Or does Julia encourage a single top level module?

Comment: you should `include("A.jl")` before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good example of a package with many internal modules, see the [Debug package](https://github.com/toivoh/Debug.jl).